# how to get antd datePicker value in format after submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

> i build a form with Ant design,there is a datepicker input and i need to select
> date in a specific date format but when i press submit the date send without any
> format. how can i get the date on format after submit the form data

```
      import { Button, Form, Input, DatePicker } from 'antd';
        const App = () => {
          const onFinish = (value) => {
             console.log(value);
           };
       return (
          <Form name="form_item_path" layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
             <Form.Item name="firstName" label="First Name">
                <Input />
             </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="start-date">
            <DatePicker className='input w-full' format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"/>
          </Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
             Submit
          </Button>
       </Form>
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the format you are getting? Is it correct to presume that this is being sent to an Express API in your control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following example

you need to convert it to required format using

```
startdate: value["start-date"].format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

App.jsx

```js
import { Button, Form, Input, DatePicker } from "antd";
import "./index.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
const App = () => {

  const onFinish = (value) => {
    let user = {
      firstname: value.firstName,
      startdate: value["start-date"].format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")  //Add your required date format here
    };
    console.log("Date in proper format", user);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="form_item_path" layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item name="firstName" label="First Name">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="start-date">
        <DatePicker className="input w-full" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Output:

[image: output]